# Hibernate predicates - Invalid path

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, criteria-api

Let's have three entities: Event, MessageEvent and Message. MessageEvent is a subclass of Event (with correctly set DiscriminatorValue). MessageEvent has one additional property "message", which is of type Message. It is defined as below:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "MESAGE_ID", nullable = false)
private Message message;
```

Now, we're trying to set a predicate that will find all MessageEvent-s whose message's id is 2. We do it in the following way:

```
cb.equal(cb.treat(root, MessageEvent.class).join(MessageEvent_.message, JoinType.LEFT).get(Message_.id), 2)
```

The code compiles well, however, we get this error at runtime:

```
5:40:59,891 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (default task-2)  Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.id':  Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.id'
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.lookupConstant(LiteralProcessor.java:114)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:214)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:104)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1033)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1286)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4699)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4169)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2134)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2059)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2059)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:813)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:607)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
at org.hibernate//org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
```

Hibernate is apparently having a problem with the construction of the corresponding SQL query. Is the problem located in Hibernate itself or did we do anything wrong?

A minimal demo is available at https://github.com/JurajMlich/hibernate-bug-demonstration .

Tested on Java 8, Java 10 (openjdk), Wildfly 10, Wildfly 12. The same query is correctly handled when using eclipse link ORM.

Comment: We've also faced similar probjem with Hibernate. Seems that even when subclass is specified, Hibernate treats join alias as `Event`, not `MessageEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies under the hood of Hibernate. I even discovered the bug in their bug tracking system and found out that it has already been fixed - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10561 . Wildfly 12, however, uses 5.1.x . After upgrading Hibernate to 5.2.17, the problem disappeared.